# Xamarin Forms - Keep virtual keyboard visible when tapping outside entry

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard

I'm trying to create a messaging app in Xamarin Forms, but I'm having trouble with the keyboard.

I need it to stay open, even when the user press "Send". But when the button (or anywhere outside the entry) is pressed, the entry is unfocused and the keyboard gone.

Is there any way to solve this in both iOS and Android?